# Prevent TrueCrypt dismount when sleeping

Tags: encryption, sleep, truecrypt, hibernate

I have full system encryption set up with TrueCrypt across an internal SSD and a 7200rpm drive, as well as two external hard drives (both Western Digital, the drive in question is a WD Elements 3TB). All drives are encrypted using the same password.

My issue is that one of my external drives (incidentally the "backup" drive), always gets dismounted when I put my computer to sleep. This is bad because I'd like the computer to wake up at 4am, log on, mirror all drives to the backup drive, go back to sleep). However, when I wake the computer up manually all drives are still in decrypted state except the backup drive, where it prompts me for a password.

What could cause this? Can I somehow prevent that particular drive from being dismounted upon logoff/sleep? All "auto-dismount" and "hibernation" options in TrueCrypt are turned off and it works just fine for all other drives.

I realize this is not the most secure way but I'd prefer this setup.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps putting the computer to sleep causes a temporary disconnect for a particular broken device. TrueCrypt dismounts volumes stored on missing drives. Not for security reasons, but simply because it has nowhere to read the data from/write it to.

Comment: As an alternative solution you could use a script that mounts the backup device. That will require storing the password in plain, but since you have full disk encryption, it's not much worse security wise than your original solution.

Comment: The device itself is new, I don't think it's a disconnect. I'm fine with storing a script, how exactly would I go about that? Thanks!